# Laravel: Paginate json response

Tags: php, json, laravel, pagination

Im getting json data from Google Fonts and displaying it on my site.Im trying to use the laravel paginator to paginate this data because when i display it as a whole it takes a toll on performance but i havent found how to do it yet.

this is my controller

```
public function googleFonts()
{     
$url = "https://www.googleapis.com/webfonts/v1/webfonts?key={ my key here}";
 $r = collect(json_decode(file_get_contents( $url ),true));
return view ('googleFonts',compact('result'))->render();
}
```

and this is on my blade file

```
 @foreach($result->items as $font)

        <tr>
          <td>{{$font->family }}</td>
          <td <p style="font-family: '{{$font->family}}',serif;font-size: 22px">Lorem ipsum</p></td>
          <td>{{implode(', ', $font->variants) }}</td>
          <td>{{$font->category }}</td>
          <td>{{implode(', ', $font->subsets) }}</td>
          <td>{{$font->version }}</td>
        </tr>
       @endforeach
```

when i return the data without pagination everything works but when i try to paginate no matter what i try everything breaks.Any ideas would be greatly appriciated

Comment: show me the screenshots and make your question more clear and specific

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could paginate your data manually using either collection or native array by instantiate this class `Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator`.

```
// Set default page
$page = request()->has('page') ? request('page') : 1;

// Set default per page
$perPage = request()->has('per_page') ? request('per_page') : 15;

// Offset required to take the results
$offset = ($page * $perPage) - $perPage;

// At here you might transform your data into collection
$url = "https://www.googleapis.com/webfonts/v1/webfonts?key={ my key here}";
$newCollection = collect(json_decode(file_get_contents( $url ),true));

// Set custom pagination to result set
$results =  new LengthAwarePaginator(
     $newCollection->slice($offset, $perPage),
     $newCollection->count(),
     $perPage,
     $page,
     ['path' => request()->url(), 'query' => request()->query()]
);

return view('googleFonts',compact('results'));
```

Comment: i get `Undefined variable: newCollection`

Comment: `$newCollection` is a variable, observe my answer and look at this part `$newCollection = collect(json_decode(file_get_contents( $url ),true));`

Comment: actually you can call directly like the normal pagination did, as its only returned the paginator objects. Just pass the data to view like you did. See updated answer

Comment: this is what i get now `Cannot access protected property Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator::$items`    this is the view `@foreach($results->items as $font)

      <tr>
        <td>{{$font->family }}</td>
        <td <p style="font-family: '{{$font->family}}',serif;font-size: 22px">Lorem ipsum</p></td>
        <td>{{implode(', ', $font->variants) }}</td>
        <td>{{$font->category }}</td>
        <td>{{implode(', ', $font->subsets) }}</td>
        <td>{{$font->version }}</td>
      </tr>
     @endforeach'  '{{ $results->links() }}'

Comment: Its depends on your data structure. Can you show results of `dd($results)`. Put that before return view.

Comment: `LengthAwarePaginator {#719 ▼
  #total: 2
  #lastPage: 1
  #items: Collection {#720 ▼
    #items: array:2 [▼
      "kind" => "webfonts#webfontList"
      "items" => array:877 [▶]
    ]
  }
  #perPage: 15
  #currentPage: 1
  #path: "http://localhost/codefield_testing/googlefonts"
  #query: []
  #fragment: null
  #pageName: "page"
}`

Comment: Okeh, you should paginate the items itself, not the collection. Can you `dd(json_decode(file_get_contents( $url ),true))` and show the result inside pastebin

Comment: Okey, insted of `$newCollection = collect(json_decode(file_get_contents( $url ),true));`, replace with `$newCollection = collect(json_decode(file_get_contents( $url ),true)['items]);`

Comment: still geting the same error `Cannot access protected property Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator::$items`

Comment: To get the result from view, use this instead `@foreach($results->items() as $font)`. Not `$results->items`

Comment: now i get `Trying to get property 'family' of non-object`

Comment: And the item being paginated is an array, so you must accessing it using  square bracket `[]` instead of object notation `->`. E.g: `$font['family']`. Do the same to other attributes as well

Comment: wow it worked.i cannot thank you enough. ive been trying to make this work for a loong time. Thank you again !! :)

Comment: Glad to hear that. Much welcome :). You can add anything inside `lengthAwarePaginator` instance. Follow this guide `https://laravel.com/api/5.6/Illuminate/Contracts/Pagination/LengthAwarePaginator.html`

Comment: Thank you again.really appreciate it

Comment: Welcome bro :).

Comment: This worked for my case but i encounter a new problem and that is to be able to reuse the code since I will be making various calls to other endpoints, if I wanted to reuse this for a different URL within the API, is there a way to make this into a method? Perhaps in the model? Would be very useful if you could show an example, thanks!!

Comment: @Eduardo actually you can put this code anywhere you want, consider put inside Base controller's method. So whenever new controller has been created, straight away you can re-use the code.

Comment: how i implement links in the blade. and my url is just /search at first, i am post to a url action="{{/search}}" so i am not able to the get search?page:1 after post

Comment: i have tried to use $result->link() it is not displaying anything in blade